# Custom pagination in php with POST

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, pagination

What I need to do is do a pagination with PHP and Post the clicked a `href` to `PHP_SELF` and redesign the page according to it.

Here is some example code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {

    if ($i == 1)
        echo "<ul>";

    echo "<li>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"p\" value=\"". $i ."\">";
    echo "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"document.forms['page'].submit(); return false;\">";
    echo "<span>". $i ."</span></a></li>";
    if ($i == $pagecount)
    echo "</ul>";

}
```

I am listing the pages by this and what I want is to send only the clicked page number to `PHP_SELF` but it only sends the `p=2` for 2 pages (e.g. `$_POST["p"] = 2`) since the last variable hidden p is 2. How can I fix this without changing the a `href` part? My aim is to send the variable and don't want it to be seen in the URL. Thanks in any advance :)

Comment: the onclick would have to extract the relevant page number and insert it into the hidden field BEFORE you .submit() it. Why are you using POST for pagination anyways? Normally you click around results with GET requests, meaning you could embed the page number as a query parameter MUCh easier.

Comment: My aim is to send the variable and don't want it to be seen in the URL. Thanks for your reply and I know that GET is easier the only thing needed to do is set href="?p=".$i but I specifically want to do it with POST

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the code like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {

    if ($i == 1)
        echo "<ul>";

    echo "<li>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"p\" name=\"p\">";
?>
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('p').value=<?php echo $i ?>; document.forms['page'].submit(); return false;">
<?php
    echo "<span>". $i ."</span></a></li>";
    if ($i == $pagecount)
    echo "</ul>";

}
```

The a href code doesn't work under php tag. Don't know the exact reason though it must be something related with the getElementById option.